# Set theory cartesian products and difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First of all hello to everyone!

I have been stuck on the same exercise and I'm looking for proper guidance in order to solve this task.
I have $A\times(B\setminus C)=(A\times B) \setminus (A\times C)$ ( sorry for not using the proper math format on this page, I'm new so I don't know how :D), and the problem is not proving the right side but the left.($A\times (B\setminus  C)$).

I get to the point where ($x\in A$ and $y\in B$) and ($x\in A$ and $y\notin C$) and don't know what to do?

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: what do you mean by proving the left side? You are supposed to prove an equality of sets so you have to show left is a subset of right and right is a subset of left.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you are trying to prove membership in RHS implies membership in LHS.

You should then start by assuming $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(x,y)\notin A\times C$, since that's what it means to have $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\setminus (A\times C)$.

Your goal is to prove that $x\in A$ and $y \in B\setminus C$, since that's what it means to have $(x,y)\in A\times (B\setminus C)$.

This implies that $x\in A$, that $y\in B$, and that $y\notin C$. Why? Because if $(x,y)\notin A\times C$, then either $x\notin A$ or $y\notin C$ -- but you already know that $x\in A$, so it must be the case that $y\notin C$.

You should be able to proceed from here.

---

For the other direction, start by assuming that $x\in A$ and $y \in B\setminus C$, since that's what it means to have $(x,y)\in A\times (B\setminus C)$. Then $y\in B$ and $y\notin C$, so surely "$x\in A$ and $y\in B$" is true, so $(x,y)\in A\times B$. You should be able to finish the proof from here. Can you see that it is also true that $(x,y)\notin A\times C$?

Comment: I have actually done that I'm trying to prove the LHS  and that's where I'm having troubles.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood. But the proof is completely reversible. Try it!